# Android Webview Websocket

Tags: javascript, android, webview, peerjs

I am developing a hybrid android web application, using just a webview and some access to a native components.

That webpage contains a canvas and PeerJS, which creates websockets to change messages.

My problem is that on the computer(going to the same link either on the pc and android tablet) the result is different, in the computer the websocket works as it should, but in the tablet when i inspect the webview or even inside chrome browser i get the following error:

peer.js:1243 WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxx:9001/peerjs?key=peerjs&id=B&token=syfbxosdaaxp63' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed.

i already tried using wifi or LTE with the same results

Comment: What kind of code do you have? What did you tried?

Comment: for example i am having the same issue in the peerjs default examples.
http://cdn.peerjs.com/demo/chat.html
in this one if you apply it between two pc browsers perfect, now if you try it on the google chrome or similar it actually connects but disconnects fast, thing which didnt do before and was working properly

Comment: Can show me an example I don't know what examples you used.

Comment: any example even the simplest one, any example from their website or even the starting one is not working  on the android or IOS enviroment, for some strange reason

Comment: ok for some strange reason in android 6.0 in a samsung TM-805 it didnt worked and in one android 5.1 TM-535 it worked, since it was just for a proof of concept it worked, but i ended up thinking not to use peer JS has it has been abandoned for a long time